# AS3 Accessing methods in loaded swf

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I'm loading an external AS3 SWF using the Loader class but i need to access a method inside the loaded SWF. how can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

var _myVariable:* = loader.content;

_myVariable.methodInLoadedSWF();

Comment: You might want to add an interface implemented by the loaded swf, so you can cast the loader.content as it.  Might make your life easier.

Comment: How can i create an interface when it has to extend a MovieClip?